# How can I visualize geojson data?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

In other words, how does this site work: http://geojson.io/? Is it harder than it looks? github does the same thing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the question
"How can I visualize geojson data?"
or 

"how does this site work?"

Comment: both. the site visualizes geojson data.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit wide. So let me try and give you come context ...

geojson is a standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

To visualize geojson data you can just search for ***geojson viewer*** with your preferred search engine.

Github has implemented a geojson viewer for you to see a map instead of a flat file when you use http://github.com and you click on a file with geojson extension.

http://geojson.io has been implemented by [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) to illustrate geojson standard. It is actually more an editor than a viewer (so very different from github).

You can find the source code of the site on github: https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io

Leaflet supports [geojson](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson).